# Boot is long because fsck.exfat spends time because exfat volume was not unmounted cleanly

Tags: boot, fsck, exfat

I have a SDD partition in exFat in order to have a common partition between macOs and Linux Manjaro and Linux Mint.

The Manjaro boot and the Linux Mint boot are very long because fsck of exFat take arround 50 seconds :

**systemd-analyze blame | head -3**

```
48.922s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0C8B\x2d9265.service
 1.166s man-db.service
 1.111s systemd-random-seed.service
```

The reason is : volume was not unmounted cleanly (see below)

**sudo journalctl -b -u systemd-fsck***

```
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/0C8B-9265...
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: exfatfsck 1.3.0
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: Checking file system on /dev/nvme0n1p6.
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro fsck.exfat[324]: volume was not unmounted cleanly
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]: fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]: There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]: This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]:   65:01/00
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]:   Not automatically fixing this.
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]:  Automatically removing dirty bit.
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]: *** Filesystem was changed ***
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]: Writing changes.
janv. 23 21:44:29 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[319]: /dev/nvme0n1p1: 470 files, 20781/403266 clusters
janv. 23 21:44:32 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd[1]: File System Check on Root Device was skipped because of a failed condition check (Conditio>
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: File system version           1.0
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: Sector size                 512 bytes
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: Cluster size                128 KB
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: Volume size                  98 GB
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: Used space                   65 GB
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: Available space              32 GB
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: Totally 9340 directories and 48907 files.
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd-fsck[324]: File system checking finished. No errors found.
janv. 23 21:45:18 sangorys-macbookproManjaro systemd[1]: Finished File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/0C8B-9265.
```

**Please help me:**

- How can I fix this issue ?
- I guess the umount is not done correctly. Can I edit the automatic umount done on fstab configuration ?
- Or can I create a service to unmount manually and correctly the exfat partition ?

I really appreciate your help

Comment: How do you shutdown the various OSs? If you don't give a system time to shutdown, flush all its disk caches, and update the on-disk information, the disk will need an `fsck`. Or, you still have Windows "Fast Boot" enabled.

Comment: I shut down my OSs by clicking on the main menu and select the shutdown button. I guess this is the standard way to shutdown.

I guess there is a bug in the shutdown process for unmounting UDS partition. Maybe I could add a step to do it myself but I don't know how to do it. Any help for that ?